# WebSphere 7.0 to 8.5.5.14 migration failure

Tags: migration, websphere

I have a task to migrate existing configuration of IBM WebSphere Application Server ND from 7.0 to 8.5. There are already quite a few profiles I need to migrate, but I had really hard time doing that.

First, while migratimg DMGR profile, migration process somehow clears the files it needs to successfully migrte. In example, in case of DMGR where *WASPreUpgrade* happens, migration just wipes everything contained in the serverindex.xml, and because of that *WASPostUpgrade* fails with unexpected file ending error. But I eventually got that and had DMGR migrated.

Second, when I try to migrate remaining profiles - it just doing basically the same - but now REMAKING files that migration needs. For example, I have an existing 7.0 profile, and when I migrate it using both GUI or command tool (silent mode), always the same error appears:

```
MIGR0215W: The migration function cannot copy the file and open the destination file /opt/IBM/WebSphere/WSMigration/FRONT01/profiles/FRONT01/config/cells/vlocal01Cell01/gridscheduler.xml.
MIGR0286E: The migration failed to complete.
```

And whatever I try to do, WASPostUpgrade just recreating that file, but ends up it just being empty and migration process fails.
In trace files it shows an error it cannot download some .tmp file from it's filestream:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File download failed: java.io.IOException: ADFS0142E: The download%2Fcells%2Fvlocal01Cell01%2Fgridscheduler.xml1439336136072019843.tmp file path cannot be downloaded because it does not exist on the server, or the path that you specified is a directory.
```

Is there something I can do to complete migration? This happens with *EVERY* existing profile, exact same error.

I have SUSE Linux on the serevr and everything runs under IBM specific user wsadmin.